# Batch update properties with values calculated from their old values

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible (and how) to update properties using their old values as part of their new values?

Pseudo SQL equivalent would be

```
UPDATE File
SET Path = @newDir + SUBSTRING(Path, LENGTH(@oldDir))
WHERE Path LIKE @oldDir + '%'
```

And as a concrete example (@oldDir = /pics/, @newDir = /images/)

```
/pics/1.jpg => /images/1.jpg
/pics/2.jpg => /images/2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mika, 
No, that isn't possible using the Patch API.
You would have to query / save those documents yourself.